# Проблема с передачей переменных

Tags: php

Делаю оплату, есть 2 формы. Одна ведет запись в базу данных(в этом же файле создал сессию, в которой храню переменные total и ordid). При нажатии на кнопку на первой форме после добавления в базу происходит перенаправление на форму оплаты, там я вызываю сессию, в которой хранил 2 переменных. Переменная total вызвалась, а ordid нет. Ошибка  Trying to get property 'ordid' of non-object.

```
        <?php
$sql="SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS ordid FROM orders;";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$ordid=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
    <form  method="post">
                <h2>Оформление Заказа</h2>
                <div class="adr">
                    <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Введите свой адрес" required>
                </div>
                <div class="ord-detail">
                    <h3 class="py-4 float-right">Total :₽ <?php echo $total->total; ?></h3>
                    <h3 class="py-4 float-right">Номер Заказа: <?php echo $ordid -> ordid;?></h3>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $total->total; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="ordid" value="<?php echo $ordid->ordid; ?>">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Оплата" name="orderplace">
        </form> 
    </section>
 

<?php

function setPaymentData($ordid,$total){
    $_SESSION['payment']['ordid']=$_POST['ordid'];
    $_SESSION['payment']['price']=$_POST['total'];
}
        
?>

    session_start();
include("config.php");
if(!empty($_SESSION['payment'])){
    $total= $_SESSION['payment']['price']; 
    $ordid = $_SESSION['payment']['ordid'];
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ПYШКА</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['payment'])): ?>
<form method="POST" action="https://yoomoney.ru/quickpay/confirm">
            <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="4100118422196682"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quickpay-form" value="button"/>
            <input type="text" name="sum" value="<?php echo $total->total; ?>" data-type="number"/>
            <input type="text" name="ordid" value="<?php echo $ordid->ordid; ?>" data-type="number"/>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Оплата" name="orderplace">
</form> 
<?php endif;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну так посмотрите что там внутри Вашего `$_SESSION['payment']`.

Comment: Передаю в неё значения из первой формы

Comment: Отлично, сделайте `var_dump()` или `print_r()`, ошибка `Trying to get property 'ordid' of non-object` обычно возникает не просто так.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)